# How can I debug/emulate Pointer Events?

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I'd like to support multi touch and pen/stylus input for my application using [Pointer Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events).

Is there a way to debug touch/pen input on a desktop without any input hardware like this? I would like to emulate several situations, like hovering with a pen without touching, or multitouch gestures. I prefer not to buy an expensive iPad or Surface Tablet just to debug pointer events.